# ¿Detectar cuando un texto no cabe en un UI Label?

Tags: xcode, swift3, interfaz-gráfica

En mi app puse un `UILabel` y dentro puse un texto, pero al parecer el texto es más largo de lo que puede caber, y yo quisiera saber si se puede detectar cuando un texto es demasiado largo, para así poder bajar el tamaño de la fuente mediante código con un `while` o algo por el estilo.

Algo así es lo que estoy buscando.

```
while label.textoMuyLargo {
   label.sizeFont = label.sizeFont -1
}
```

[image]

**¿Cómo se detecta cuando un texto es demasiado largo para un UI Label?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario cambiar el tamaño de la *font* a mano. Para eso puedes usar la propiedad `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` de `UILabel`.

Por ejemplo, este código:

```
label.numberOfLines = 1
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

La propiedad [`minimumScaleFactor`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilabel/1620544-minimumscalefactor) se utiliza para calcular el tamaño mínimo de la *font*. Es decir, el tamaño de la misma se reduce hasta un mínimo de `label.minimumScaleFactor * label.font.pointSize`. Por ejemplo, con un `minimumScaleFactor` de `0.5` y una *font* de tamaño `16px`, el tamaño mínimo utilizado será de `8px`.

Comment: Que hace la función `minimumScaleFactor`?

Comment: @JoseFabio Agregué la información a la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Mejor podrías establecer (desde el interfaz *builder* las siguientes propiedades

```
numberOfLines = 0
```

Y con `autolayout` el `Height` con prioridad `250`.

Eso hará que la etiqueta crezca en función del tamaño del texto. Es mucho mas limpio y sencillo. Trata de evitar código de UI en el *controller*.